# When to call tableView.selectRow to avoid UITableViewAlertForCellForRowAtIndexPathAccessDuringUpdate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In implementing support for multiple selection of rows of a `UITableView`, I'm using a private variable `rowSelectionState` which is managed during `didSelectRow` and `didDeselectRow`.  The current state of `rowSelectionState` is then used to control display of the properly selected rows to the user via calls to `configureCellSelectionState()` `cellForRowAt`.  Technically as of iOS 14.4, this does what it is supposed to do, with the caveat that iOS dumps a bunch of `UITableViewAlertForCellForRowAtIndexPathAccessDuringUpdate` warnings in XCode.

```
    private var rowSelectionState = [IndexPath: Bool]()

    func configureCellSelectionState(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard tableView.isEditing else { return }
        if rowSelectionState[indexPath] ?? false {
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        } else {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.isEditing {
            rowSelectionState[indexPath] = true
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.isEditing {
            rowSelectionState[indexPath] = false
        }
    }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        
        if !editing {
            rowSelectionState.removeAll()
        }
    }
```

Calling `configureCellSelectionState()` inside of `cellForRowAt` is how this was originally written.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: rowCellId, for: indexPath)
        configureCellSelectionState(indexPath)
        return cell
    }
```

After taking closer notice of the stream of warnings, some searching StackOverflow led me to call `configureCellSelectionState()` inside of `willDisplay` rather than `cellForRowAt`.  Unfortunately, the warnings are still there.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        configureCellSelectionState(indexPath)
    }
```

Example warning:

```
2021-02-09 09:12:14.119983-0500 XXX [55266:1705708] [Assert] 
Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is not allowed. 
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForCellForRowAtIndexPathAccessDuringUpdate to catch this in the debugger and see what caused this to occur. 
Perhaps you are trying to ask the table view for a cell from inside a table view callback about a specific row? 
Table view: <UITableView: 0x7b7800045c00; frame = (0 0; 390 844); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b0c000fee50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b08002be520>; contentOffset: {0, -143}; contentSize: {390, 264}; adjustedContentInset: {143, 0, 143, 0}; dataSource: <XXX.YYYTableViewController: 0x7b640006b800>>
```

So the question is, what is the "proper" way to implement this kind of feature while avoiding the `UITableViewAlertForCellForRowAtIndexPathAccessDuringUpdate` warning?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `tableView.selectRow` or `tableView.deselectRow` while displaying the cell, call it instead from `viewDidLoad` for your view controller. Or perhaps after setting the value of `rowSelectionState`, if that happens after loading the view controller already.

The issue is that you're inside a `UITableView` delegate method when you're trying to change the selection state, so it's not going to work properly.

Note also that you can check the `indexPathsForSelectedRows` property on `UITableView` so that when you do make changes to `rowSelectionState`, you can just update the selection state of only those rows that need it. But again, do this not when you're in the middle of a `UITableView` delegate method.

Also, from the looks of it, you're trying to use `rowSelectionState` to track which ones are already in a selected state, so maybe you need to just reference the `indexPathsForSelectedRows` property.

Comment: The use of the ```rowSelectionState``` is to ensure that the selection state endures while scrolling.  You suggesting that the ```UITableView``` correctly manages its own selection state now (i.e., in iOS 14? - Apple docs state this existed in iOS 5) and exposes that information via the ```indexPathsForSelectedRows```?  BTW, I've found that using ```tableView.selectRow``` in ```viewDidLoad``` immediately after ```tableView.reloadData``` results in the same warnings, suggesting selectRow is being executed before reloadData completes, thus why I did not believe doing so was the ultimate answer.